# Trying to get dictionary to add items as a list is iterated over, but not working. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I am trying to make a dictionary of dataframes, so I could plot them onto a graph. However, I when I print(data), it only gives the df for only one file in the list filter_data.

I tried to print inside the for loop, and it gives the values i want, a dictionary of files as keys, and the corresponding data frame as the values. I don't know why this isn't working outside of the loop, but is inside.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
def process_data():
    data = {}
    for i in filter_data():
        fname = i.split('/')[-1]
        #print(fname)
        figname = fname.split('.')[-2]
        molname = figname.split('_')[-5]
        molname = str(molname[1:])
        colname2 =' & '.join(figname.split('_')[-1:]) if 'only' not in figname else '_'.join(figname.split('_')[-2:])
        colname = '_'.join(figname.split('_')[-2:])
        repname = figname.split('_')[-4]
        with open('{}'.format(i),'r') as f:
            x, y = [], []
            for line in f:
                if line.startswith('@'): continue
                line = line.split()

                 if len(line) == 2:
                     x.append(line[0])
                     y.append(line[1])

        x = [float(l)/1000.0 for l in x]
        y = [float(l) for l in y]
        df = pd.DataFrame({'RMSD (nm)': x, 'Time (ps)': y})
        data = {'{m}_{b}_{f}'.format(b = repname, m = molname, f = colname) : df}
    #print(df.head())
    print(data)

#only gives one value
process_data()
```

Comment: You're overwriting `data` in each iteration of your loop. Try changing the last line of your `for` loop to `data['{m}_{b}_{f}'.format(b = repname, m = molname, f = colname)] = df`

Comment: @pault Oh, I see, I am overwriting it. Thank you! It is working correctly now!